# FASTAPI SSO with Azure AD using SAML

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml, fastapi

Can someone please point me to any package that can be used in **fast-api** to integrate **sso** with **azure ad** using **saml** ?

I have seen some packages but they do it with oauth.
https://intility.github.io/fastapi-azure-auth/

Is there any that exists with SAML? Thanks

Comment: Please check if [this](https://pypi.org/search/?q=fastapi-aad-sso-saml&o=) helps in anyway.